# How to send bitmap to webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, bitmap

I want to send **Bitmap** image to webservice.

Webservice code :

```
[WebMethod]
public AuthenticatedUserInfo CheckUserAuthentication2(Bitmap fingerImage)
{
}
```

Here is my client function :

```
private void SendBiometricInfo2(Bitmap image)
{
    _service = new Client.BioAuthenticationService.BioAuthenticationService();

    Client.BioAuthenticationService.AuthenticatedUserInfo userInfo = _service.CheckUserAuthentication2(image);
}
```

However i get an error in :

```
_service.CheckUserAuthentication2(image);
```

Here is the error message :

```
cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'MIA.BioID.UserAuthentication.Client.BioAuthenticationService.Bitmap'
```

Could you please help how to handle this issue ?

Comment: Fully qualify Bitmap in the parameter for SendBiometricInfo2.

Comment: @AWinkle sorry but i didnt understand what you mean .

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio to create the web service?

Comment: @RickS yes i am using vs2012

Answer (score 0):

have you got another object or method called Bitmap in your webservice?

Alternatively define the bitmap as System.Drawing.Bitmap in your webservice definition

Comment: i implement using System.Drawing;  so your solution does not solve my problem  :((

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public AuthenticatedUserInfo CheckUserAuthentication2(System.Drawing.Bitmap fingerImage)
        {
        }

Comment: I also tried this way.. But i didnt solved. It is the same thing which i did with using ..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you create the reference to your service there should be an option under the Advanced button that says "Reuse types in referenced assembly".  Uncheck it and see if that helps.

Comment: How can i find this properties ?